# Ubuntu with Rodecaster Pro (USB Soundcard)

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, audio-jack

I switched from MacOS to Ubuntu 20.04 and I really like it but I cannot get a USB Soundcard running. It's the Rodecaster Pro and they don't offer a Linux driver but I read about ALSA drivers.

When I run

```
lssub
```

I see the Rodecaster Pro in the list which is good. But I cannot see it in my audio devices.

[Rodecaster Pro USB device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUeye.png)

I modified the USB audio config file with

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/snd-usb-audio
```

[snd-usb-audio entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I82Ww.png)

I already tried:

```
pulseaudio, alsa-utils, alsomixer
```

Do you have any ideas or recommendations?

Thank you.

Comment: Ok, thank you. :-)

Comment: Since Ubuntu 20.04 is officially released I want to ask the community again for help.

Thank you all.

Comment: did you find a solution?